# How to block Traffic Control (tc) operation if started as non-root?

Tags: permissions, tc

I disallowed users to launch tc binary from standard location but if they download it from network to home directory they can view traffic control settings. How can I disallow interaction between tc (launched as non-root) and kernel?

Comment: Why should you have normal users in critical servers?

Comment: It is an embedded system, so the user have to connect remotely and get a limited set of tools.

Comment: Change rights of the tc binary so non-root users cannot read it.

Comment: They can find the binary anywhere, download it to a home catalog, set execution permission (seems I can't prevent it) and run. Can I break tc operation in this situation?

Comment: Give them a restricted shell then, and limit them for a few defined operations.

Comment: Does it _really_ matter that a determined user can read the `tc` configuration? (It may do; I don't know. Hence the question.)